# Value is not updated to database for EF 4.1 using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

I have did this line of code but the value is not get updated.I have used the rad control for that.

```
db.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
var c1 = (from c in db.Currency where c.ThreeLetterIsoCode == "1" select c).First();
c1.ThreeLetterIsoCode = "Updatesd";
db.UpdateObject(c1);
db.SaveChanges();
radDataServiceDataSource1.SubmitChanges();
```

There is no exception but it does not get updated.

The service is:

```
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
{
  // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
  // Examples:
  // config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("MyEntityset", EntitySetRights.AllRead);                 
  // config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("MyServiceOperation", ServiceOperationRights.All);
  config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
  config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
}

protected override ObjectContext CreateDataSource()
{
  BaazaarDbContext nw = new BaazaarDbContext();

  // Configure DbContext before we provide it to the
  // data services runtime.
  nw.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

  // Get the underlying ObjectContext for the DbContext.
  var context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)nw).ObjectContext;

  // Return the underlying context.
  return context;
}
```

I have inserted a row it get inserted.  Please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

If the ThreeLetterIsoCode is a key property then this is by design. You can't change a key property of an existing entity, since that would change the entity identity which is not supported in OData.
If the ThreeLetterIsoCode is a normal property then the above should work. In that case could you please grab a trace of the request/response (using for example Fiddler) and post it here as well?

Comment: Yes absolutely true.I repeatedly did the same mistake then suddenly i discover the fact i try to update the [key] attribute of the code.and when i do the same for another non key property.It worked.Thank you.